# Regex pattern for filename in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have groovy script which list filenames based on argument passed.
And I want to list filename containing **b** so, I'm providing filename in regex pattern as argument like: **`(*.)b(*.).*`**

But while running the command I'm getting: **-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('**

Comment: Can you show the relevant statements from the script?

Answer (score 1):

```
new File("./folder/to/scan").eachFileMatch( ~/.*b.*/ ){file->
    println file
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I have to pass as argument, by hardcoding it is working.

Comment: Aman, Could you modify your question and specify what do you need to pass as argument and how you call the groovy script.